# Find biggest value of $z$, equation system

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

How do I solve the following problem:

Find the biggest value of z:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x+\frac{1}{y}&=10 \\
y+\frac{1}{z}&=10 \\
z+\frac{1}{x}&=10
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer is $5 + \sqrt{24}$.

Comment: Biggest $z$ was the one in the picture you posted ;-) I edited the post for you, please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) next time.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  by brute force:

$$
\begin{align}
z = 10 - \frac{1}{x} & = 10 - \cfrac{1}{10 - \cfrac{1}{y}} = 10 - \cfrac{1}{10 - \cfrac{1}{10-\cfrac{1}{z}}}
\end{align}
$$

After routine manipulations, the equation reduces to $\;99z^2-990z+99=0\,$.